# multiple rows in form for the same entity in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I create a simple form with multiple rows:

Controller:

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Product');
    $products = $repository->findAll();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $forms[] = $this->createForm(new ProductType, $product)->createView();
    }

    return $this->render('MBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('form' => $forms);        

}
```

I render this in a twig:

```
<form action="{{ path('_submit') }}" method="post">
{% for key, formData in forms %}
    {{ form_row(formData.id) }}
    {{ form_row(formData.name) }}
    {{ form_row(formData.nameEnglish) }}
    <br clear="all" />
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

When i submit form each of my input field set has the same name attributes and i get only the last one. How to grab all the rows and validate them in my submitAction() controller? Each input needs to have unique name, right? ... and perhaps i need to set somehow name="something[name][]" but how to do it?

Comment: Take a look at the collections field group: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.  You will end up passing $products to your form.

Comment: Can you give me an example. I dont understand how in this case collection would work

Comment: Make yourself a ProductsType form and embed ProductType as a collection.

Comment: im trying and im getting "Neither property "products" nor method "getProducts()"....

Comment: You need to pass an array to the form with an element named products.  $data = array('products' => $products);  It will make more sense once you have it working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok Cerad was right with his comment and we have to use collection for this. It may sound like a nonsense at first but it kinda is right. It took me a while to get head around it.

So i had to create a ProductsType which is an arrayCollection and inserts each Product. (just like in documentation with Task and tags)

I used that:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ExampleBundle:Product');
$products = $repository->findAll();

$productCollection = new Products;

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productCollection->getProducts()->add($product);
}

$collection = $this->createForm(new ProductsType, $productCollection);

return $this->render('ExampleBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
    'collection' => $collection->createView()
        ));
```

Then in twig i do:

```
<div class="products">
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {{ form_row(product.id) }}
        {{ form_row(product.name) }}
        {{ form_row(product.description) }}
        <br clear="all" />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Job done.

And even you can apply themes to each row by this:

```
{% block _productsType_products_entry_name_row %}
    <div class="yourDivName">{{ block('form_widget') }}</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block _productsType_products_entry_description_row %}
    <div class="yourDivDescription">{{ block('form_widget') }}</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Cool stuff!

Comment: You could simplify just a bit with: $productCollection = array('products' => $products);  No real need (in this case) to make a Products class.

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike Could you please show how looks like the class ProductsType ?