# symfony2 Submit multiple entities in a single form

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

i'm using the last symfony version and i'm tring to submit multiple rows of the same entity using the same form.

table 'config' structure (it's key value) :

```
-----------------------------
| id | key_name | key_value |
-----------------------------
```

So i'd like to add/update many rows using the same form

any idea to do it ? i tried to follow this solution [multiple rows in form for the same entity in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359138/multiple-rows-in-form-for-the-same-entity-in-symfony2) but it does't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use [collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). It will allow you to dynamicly add rows in form.