# Multiple rows from the same entity in single form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Doctrine extensions [tree Entity](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/tree.md) which I want to put entirely (or only a node and all its children) in a form. That is, I want to be able to modify the entire (sub)tree in a single form. I have taken a look at “[multiple rows in form for the same entity in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359138/multiple-rows-in-form-for-the-same-entity-in-symfony2),” however, I'm unable to apply it to a tree with all its children in Symfony3.

I was thinking of something as a controller like

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
$tree = $repository->children(null, true);

$form = $this->createForm(CategoryType::class, $tree);
```

and a `CategoryType` like

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title');
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Category::class /* or should it be `null`? */,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Just like in the answer you linked to, you need to have a collection of forms... http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: @ehymel I see, but how do I avoid adding a ‘container’ `Category` that holds all the children? I just want to pass an array to the form.

Comment: Don't avoid it. Your "container" will be nothing more than a parameter within your root `Category` that holds the array of children. Call that parameter `$categories` and add the appropriate getter/setter methods. Of course the setter will be `public function addCategory(Category $category) {}`.

Comment: @timothymctim You can consult my solution for your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953858/how-to-create-a-form-with-multiple-rows-of-one-entity-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Controller:

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
    $categories = $repository->children(null, false); // get the entire tree including all descendants

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(array('categories' => $categories));
    $form->add('categories', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => CategoryType::class,
    ));
    $form->add('edit', SubmitType::class);

    $form = $form->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        // $data['categories'] contains an array of AppBundle\Entity\Category
        // use it to persist the categories in a foreach loop
    }

    return $this->render(...)
}
```

The `CategoryType` is just like ‘normal,’ e.g., the one in my question.

It is key to create the form builder with `array('categories' => $categories)` and add a form `CollectionType` field with the name `categories`.