# Is it possible to create multiple entities from request with symfony form?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I use symfony forms for handling API requests. I have Event entity and EventForm class. I need to make bulk API for creating multiple events at a time. How can I reuse existing form to create multiple Event entities? Request will look like this:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Event One",
            "description": "",
            "startsAt": "2019-08-16T16:00:00+0300",
            "endsAt": "2019-08-16T17:00:00+0300",
            "allDay": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Event Two",
            "description": "",
            "startsAt": "2019-08-16T16:00:00+0300",
            "endsAt": "2019-08-16T17:00:00+0300",
            "allDay": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I read about forms embedding https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_collections.html and it seems that it's not my case, 'cause I don't need to set multiple children to parent entity, but just create multiple events.

Here is my EventForm class:

```php
class EventForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('description', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => '',
            ])
            ->add('startsAt', DateTimeType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'widget'   => 'single_text',
            ])
            ->add('endsAt', DateTimeType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'widget'   => 'single_text',
            ])
            ->add('allDay', CheckboxType::class, [
                'required' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

I create BulkEventForm class:

```php
class BulkEventForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('events', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => EventForm::class
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

I expect that I get an array or collection of events, but after handling the request form data is:

```php
[
    'events' => []
]
```

Is it possible to get the expected result without looping through request and creating multiple forms?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359138/multiple-rows-in-form-for-the-same-entity-in-symfony2 ?

Comment: @AndreaManzi I've just tried that, got exception

`Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "title". at /var/www/web-server/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php:173`


Though all parameters aren't empty

Comment: I assume, that you provide some number of `Event` objects in the `createForm` call, which don't have a default value (a string) for the `title` property? thus accessing them returns null, which might produce this message ... ? you should set `allow_add` on your `CollectionType` though, if your building the forms in the template via javascript from the prototype, you don't probably need to provide them when creating the form